# The FCM message data is not received in the ionic application

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have a simple Ionic implementation (Android) to receive message from FCM.
When a message is sent from the Firebase console, the notification arrives and an alert is displayed but the message data is not displayed.

This is the code (app.component.ts):

```
  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public fcm: FCM, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');

platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {

    console.log(token);

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: '¡New token!',
      message: token,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('OK');
            this.navCtrl.push('DetailPage');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  alert.present();

  });

  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
    alert('message received');
    if(data.wasTapped) {
      console.log(data);
     console.info("Received in background");
    } else {
    //  console.log(data);
     console.info("Received in foreground");
    }; 
  });
```

For example, when the message is sent from the Firebase console:

- Message Text: This is a test!
- Optional label: New message.

the alert('message received') in the application is displayed, but the output of the console.log(data) into the fcm.onNotification().subscribe() is:

```
> {wasTapped: false}
{"wasTapped": false}
```

How can I get the message data? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: but you have comment console.log() when it is received in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

For data to have information you must send the information like this from your server

```
{"message":{ 
           "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...", 
           "notification":{ "title":"Portugal vs.Denmark", "body": 
                             "great match!" },
           "data" : { "Nick" : "Mario", "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark" } } }
```

Where message.data is the data output you want to send